# Tkinter not displaying dropdown value

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu, typeerror

First time with drop down menus. Very basic.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title("Drop down menus")
root.iconbitmap("D:/de_clutter/comdes/tkinter/images/__icon_test.ico")

clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set("Saber")
def Choice():
    l1 = Label(root, text = clicked.get()).pack()

drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, "Saber", "Archer", "Assasin", "Lancer", "Berserker", "Caster", "Rider", command = Choice)
drop.pack()


mainloop()
```

I want it to say what I picked. For example, if in the drop down menu I pick "Archer", I want it to display under it that I picked archer. Instead it gives me a type error:

```
TypeError: Choice() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: The callback of `OptionMenu` expects an argument: the value selected.

Comment: @acw1668 what does that mean? and how should I change it?

Comment: That means you should use `def Choice(value):` instead and you can use `value` and no need to call `clicked.get()`.

Comment: @acw1668 that is so strange why is it only this way for OptionMenu while in Checkbox and the RadioButtons you don't need this

Comment: It is the design of `tkinter`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear. `Choice()` doesn't accept but you are passing arguments when you click the button. `def Choice(*args)` allows **Choice** to accept arguments. Here's the corrected code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title("Drop down menus")
root.iconbitmap("D:/de_clutter/comdes/tkinter/images/__icon_test.ico")

clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set("Saber")

def Choice(*args):
    l1 = Label(root, text = clicked.get()).pack()

drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, "Saber", "Archer", "Assasin", "Lancer", "Berserker", "Caster", "Rider", command=Choic
drop.pack()


mainloop()
```

[image]